# Stabilization of non-autonomuous 1-d wavs equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, stability, hyperbolic-dynamics, wave-equation

I want to ask two questions about the stabilization of the equation $$\eqalign{
  & {y_{tt}} = k(t,x){y_{xx}}+a(t,x){y_t}+ b(t,x){y_x}+ c(t,x){y_x}   +d(t,x)y   \ \ (t,x) \in {\text{ }}(0,\infty ) \times (0 ,1)  \cr 
  & y(t,0) = y(t,1) = 0 \cr} $$ 
The first one:  Is there exists an exponential stabilization result concerning the above equation?.
The second question: Is it interesting from mathematical or physical applications of this kind of equations?.
Thanks.